# Handle and thread purpose

Tags: android, multithreading, handle

i'm learning android by material given by my friend. That 1 part talk bout Handle and thread. I cant really get it meaning and purpose because I can do the same thing with normal coding.

I learn vb and java also but all is just basic bout it . Sorry if this seem stupid for you all.

What do thread and handler really work for ? as like I dont know and cant figure out what situation i need to use it.

Comment: And what is exactly your question or problem, please?

Comment: The question is too wide.

Comment: http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidBackgroundProcessing/article.html see this

Answer (score 1):

Threads are used when you want to achieve parallel processing which means that an action can be operated without waiting for another action to finish its task.

Handler is used inside your thread when managing UI components.

Answer (score 0):

```
1. Android's user interface thread 
1.1. Main thread
Android modifies the user interface and handles input events from one single user interface thread. This thread is also called the main thread.

Android collects all events in a queue and processed an instance of the Looper class.
```

5.1. Purpose of the Handler class 
    The Handler class can be used to register to a thread and provides a simple channel to send data to this thread. 
    A Handler object registers itself with the thread in which it is created. For example, if you create a new instance of the Handler class in the onCreate() method of your activity, the resulting Handler object can be used to post data to the main thread.
    The data which can be posted via the Handler class can be an instance of the Message or the Runnable class.

For more information you can go through this link :
http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidBackgroundProcessing/article.html
http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html